# Android modify ImageView parameters after adding to Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, layoutparams

If I have a `ImageView` `foo` I can modify its parameters before adding it to a Layout with:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams testParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500,500);
foo.setLayoutParams(testParams);
```

then I add `foo` to the layout with:

```
exampleLayout.addView(foo);
```

How can I modify the parameters after adding `foo` to the layout? (I read that there was a different process if `foo` was already added to the layout)

Comment: Do the same thing after adding the view and call foo.invalidate();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still edit after adding the foo. 
on your foo add the id at runtime. Lets say. `foo.setId(23);`
now at runtime `examplelayout.findviewbyid(23)` will give you your view. 
Now you can update params on that. and call invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify layout parameters before adding to its parent, but if you want to modify it, first find it by its ID, then use `getLayoutParams()` method and modify it, then set it again using `setLayoutParams()`.